# Disapearing icons in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: menu

The icons in the RWD theme responsive menu disappear when the screen size is that of a smartphone device...although the menus work.

This did not happen at the time after installation from scratch the first time. How can I fix this and have the responsive menu icons back?

Ivan

Answer (score 1):

Check if the icon_sprite.png is the directory: skin/frontend/yourtheme/yourthemename/images/

If it is, check if the icon_sprite is the correct one.

Bouwe